# select 4 answers for each questin from 2 tables Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables "question" and "answer", I need to select 4 random questions with their 4 answers

I tried this: (but return only 1 answer for each question)

```
SELECT question.id,question.text,answer.id,answer.text
FROM question
LEFT JOIN answer ON answer.question_id = question.id
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
limit 4
```

tables:

question

```
id     text
1     where is...?
2     is .....?
3     How old ...?
4     from where...?
5     where are ...?
6     is England ...?
```

answer

```
id   question_id     text
1         1           bla..
2         1           18
3         1           19
4         1           jj
5         2           kk
6         2           82
7         2           77
8         2           77
9         3           6
10        3           2
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select de random questions with a subquery, then join the answer table:

```
SELECT q.id,
    q.text,
    a.id AS a_id -- always use an alias when you have duplicate coloumn names
    a.text a_text
FROM
    (SELECT
         id, text
     FROM
         questions
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) q
JOIN
    answers a
    ON a.question_id = q.id
```

Edit: answer was posted while typing

Comment: working fine but it takes long time around 7 seconds to finish

Comment: That is caused by ORDER BY RAND()

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q.id,Q.text,answer.id,answer.text
FROM

     (SELECT * FROM question
      ORDER BY RAND( )
      limit 4) Q
     LEFT OUTER JOIN answer
     ON answer.question_id = Q.id;
```

Comment: receive: #1054 - Unknown column 'Q.id' in 'field list'